# Different project types in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio

Excuse me for the silly question but I just started with Visual Studio.
I have two different VS 2010 projects.
For the first one when I select "Publish Site" I get this window

[image: Publish Web Site dialog]

But in the second project I get this window.

[image: Publish Web dialog]

Is there any way to convert a Web Application into a Web Site?

Is there any difference in the two project? Is one project a web site and the second a web application? How to distinguish among the two types?

Comment: plenty of info about this subject online. Yes web site and web application are different things and are published differently.

Comment: It is easy to convert a web site to a web app but not the other way round.  This is a bit subjective but web site projects are a bit amateurish I have yet to encounter a professional developer that uses them.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct - the first one is a Web Site Project and the second is a Web Application Project.  The easiest way to check is to look for the .csproj file - this isn't needed by the Web Site Project as it simply includes all files in a specific folder.

The property pages also look significantly different for the two.

Comment: And I strongly recommend to use Web App Project, and migrate all existing Web Site Projects to Web App

Comment: Indeed - there are many advantages of the Web Application Project, and was made the default in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* convert a website to a web application.  Here is a nice [walk-through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx) on MSDN.